# Best way to call a JavaScript function from an Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I export a method to javascript window with JSNI, and I want to call this function from a applet in a GWT application..

I think that sometimes I have problems with Window context, so, I do some research and found the `JSObject` class.

I afraid with the package name (`netscape.javascript`). Is this class still be used? Is there another better way to do this?

I already tried to get applet context and show a new URl (with `javascript:myFunction();`), but,   in some browsers it redirects the user to a new blank window...

What can I do to make it works best as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"show a new URI .. in some browsers it redirects the user to a new blank window"*  Which browsers?

Comment: As I tested, Firefox 8+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `netscape.javascript` package is included with every Oracle JRE that I am aware of.  Not entirely sure about the others.